# It's possible to create an channel between redux and firestore through redux-observable epic?

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

it's possible to create an epic to make data flows from firestore through redux? I'm trying do listen to firestore changes an put that on my redux but I get this error on my epic:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

From what I get until now this error is happenning because the epic is dispatching an observable instead of a object right?

how can I convert this observable that contains the list of changes inside it and dispatch all changes to redux?

```
const handlePosts = snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      return {
        type: ADD_POST,
        info: change.doc.data()
      }
    }
    if (change.type === 'modified') {
      return {
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        info: change.doc.data()
      }
    }
    if (change.type === 'removed') {
      return {
        type: REMOVE_POST,
        info: change.doc.data()
      }
    }
  });
};

const posts$ = Rx.Observable.create(observer => firestoreDb
  .collection('posts')
  .onSnapshot(observer)
);

export const firestoreStreamEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(START_FIRESTORE_STREAM)
    .switchMap(action => 
      .map((payload) => {
        handlePosts(payload);
      })
    );
```

Comment: Can you include additional clarification about what exactly you need help with? I think you might have left out code as `posts$` is not used

Comment: typing error, but the posts$ variables is returned on switchMap on my epic, I want to receive changes of a firestore/(maybe a socket) listener and pass that through my epic and put on my redux store...

Comment: Shoot sorry @Ygor it's still not clear what, exactly, you're having trouble with. Feel free to edit your question above to reduce the complexity and add clarification.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my code to reflect what I want more clearly later, sorry for disturbing...